# Identifying the closest polygon to a point dataset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, attribute-joins, relates, large-datasets

I have two large data sets one point and one polygon.

What I was looking to do was identify which polygon is closest to each point.

Hopefully I was looking for a automated process as the point data set is very large. Ideally I would like a column in the attribute table of the point data set identifying the name/reference of the nearest polygon.

Comment: What is the format of your dataset ? Sofware ?

Comment: @kcunliffe - can you load them into a database?

Comment: I don't see why not. What kind of database, Geodatabase?

Comment: What software are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using ArcGIS:

You can use the [Near tool](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#//00080000001q000000).

You can also use the Spatial Join tool and under Match Options, choose Closest.